# "advantages" and "disadvantages" should be blacklisted

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[disadvantages](/questions/tagged/disadvantages) to having them: They can't stand alone in a question.

[advantages](/questions/tagged/advantages) to blacklisting them: No one will think to use them.

Comment: Quite a lot of the questions also seem to be tagged [tag:benefits].

Comment: One may ask which are the disvantages and advantages of a given approach.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri One may ask, but that would be closed as "not constructive".  There's no good way to answer these questions, as a) advantages/disadvantages can lead into subjective territory and b) they tend to be list-like questions (listing the advantages/disadvantages) which is not a good fit for any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've:

- Removed the [advantages](/questions/tagged/advantages) tag and reviewed all the questions for closure (they were all closed)
- Removed the [disadvantages](/questions/tagged/disadvantages) tag and reviewed all the questions for closure (they were all closed)
- **BONUS!** Removed the [benefits](/questions/tagged/benefits) tag and reviewed all the questions for closure (they were all closed)

The tags will be gone in 24 hours.  I don't feel that a blacklist is appropriate, as each of these tags had less than 30 questions in each tag and that's like nuking a mosquito.

Comment: Mosquitos can [bite back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaria) :-).